# Why aren't my driver values updating?

Tags: rigging, drivers

I am currently in the process of retouching an older character of mine with a new rig i made, however, mid-way through attaching the old parts onto the new rig, the drivers on the new rig that controll the IK/FK switching stopped updating their driver values. How do i fix it?
[image: The defaut state of the driver]
[image: When the switch has moved, the driver value does not update]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I just needed to raise the value a little bit...